# SQL 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax when deleting across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, notin

I'm trying to delete specific rows in multiple log tables, for activity that is > 5 days old. but want to keep the log activity if the visitor_id is found in log_customer.

the following returns over 42 K rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM `log_url` , `log_url_info`, `log_visitor_info`, `log_visitor`
WHERE `log_url`.`visit_time` <= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5
DAY
AND `log_url`.`url_id` = `log_url_info`.`url_id` 
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` = `log_visitor`.`visitor_id`
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` = `log_visitor_info`.`visitor_id`
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` NOT IN ( select `log_customer`.`visitor_id` from `log_customer` )
```

However, this returns the sql 1064 error:

```
DELETE
FROM `log_url` , `log_url_info`, `log_visitor_info`, `log_visitor`
WHERE `log_url`.`visit_time` <= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5
DAY
AND `log_url`.`url_id` = `log_url_info`.`url_id` 
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` = `log_visitor`.`visitor_id`
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` = `log_visitor_info`.`visitor_id`
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` NOT IN ( select `log_customer`.`visitor_id` from `log_customer` )
```

Error messages:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE log_url.visit_time 
<= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND log_url.url_id' at line 3
```

I also get ...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE log_url.visit_time
<= STR_TO_DATE('2014-08-21 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:' at line 3
```

...if I replace `NOW()` ... with `<= STR_TO_DATE( '2014-08-21 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )`

Comment: What's the specific error message? That's likely to help you figure out where your MySQL syntax error lies.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `log_url`.`visit_time` <= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND `log_url`.`url_id`' at line 3

I also get 

      #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `log_url`.`visit_time` <= STR_TO_DATE('2014-08-21 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:' at line 3

if I replace NOW() ... with 
    <= STR_TO_DATE( '2014-08-21 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be...

```
DELETE `log_url` , `log_url_info`, `log_visitor_info`, `log_visitor`
FROM `log_url` , `log_url_info`, `log_visitor_info`, `log_visitor`
WHERE `log_url`.`visit_time` <= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 DAY
AND `log_url`.`url_id` = `log_url_info`.`url_id` 
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` = `log_visitor`.`visitor_id`
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` = `log_visitor_info`.`visitor_id`
AND `log_url`.`visitor_id` NOT IN ( select `log_customer`.`visitor_id` from log_customer` )
```

or even...

```
DELETE u 
     , ui
     , vi
     , v
  FROM log_url u
  JOIN log_url_info ui
    ON ui.url_id = u.url_id 
  JOIN log_visitor_info vi
    ON vi.visitor_id = u.visitor_id 
  JOIN log_visitor v
    ON v.visitor_id = u.visitor_id 
 WHERE u.visit_time <= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 5 DAY
   AND u.visitor_id NOT IN ( SELECT visitor_id FROM log_customer)
```

Comment: of course! delete `log_url` , `log_url_info`, `log_visitor_info`, `log_visitor` from .. .

Thanks for the much more elegant option with the join!